# I can't open the jar file of the project

Tags: java

I have a project that I need to have its jar file , but it doesn't open , can anyone help me please, I need it as soon as possible for my university . And here is the whole code :

```
package huffmanproject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class huffmanproject {

    public static class HuffNode implements Comparable<HuffNode> {

        public int value;
        public int weight;
        public HuffNode leftTree;
        public HuffNode rightTree;
        public HuffNode parent;

        public HuffNode() {
            parent = null;
        }

        public HuffNode( int v, int w, HuffNode lTree, HuffNode rTree, HuffNode par ) {
            value = v;
            weight = w;
            leftTree = lTree;
            rightTree = rTree;
            parent = par;
         }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(HuffNode rhs) {
            return weight - rhs.weight;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            String str = "";
            str += this.value;
            return str;
        }
    }

    public static class HuffTree {

        private int size = 0;
        private HuffNode root = new HuffNode();
        private PriorityQueue<HuffNode> huffQueue = new PriorityQueue();
        public ArrayList<String> pathTable = new ArrayList();
        public ArrayList<Character> valueTable = new ArrayList();

        public HuffTree(int[] freq, char[] code) {

            this.size = freq.length;

            if (freq.length != code.length) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Error: Character and code length mismatch.");
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < this.size; i++) {
                huffQueue.offer(new HuffNode(code[i], freq[i], null, null, null));
            }
            createTree();
            createTable(this.root, "");
        }

        private void createTree() {
            while (huffQueue.size() > 1) {
                HuffNode tempL = huffQueue.poll();
                HuffNode tempR = huffQueue.poll();
                HuffNode parent = new HuffNode(0, tempL.weight+tempR.weight, tempL, tempR, null);
                tempL.parent = parent;
                tempR.parent = parent;
                huffQueue.offer(parent);
                this.size++;
            }
            this.root = huffQueue.peek();
        }
        private void createTable(HuffNode curr, String str) {
            if (curr == null) return;
            if (curr.leftTree == null && curr.rightTree == null) {
                char tempChar;
                if (curr.value == 32)
                    tempChar = ' ';

                if (curr.value == 10)
                    tempChar = 'n';

                else 
                    tempChar = (char)curr.value;
                this.valueTable.add(tempChar);
                this.pathTable.add(str);
            }
            str += "0";
            createTable(curr.leftTree, str);
            str = str.substring(0, str.length()-1);
            str += "1";
            createTable(curr.rightTree, str);
        }
        String tacks = "";
        public void getTree(HuffNode curr) {
            if (curr == null) return;
            if (curr.leftTree == null && curr.rightTree == null) {
                switch (curr.value) {
                    case 32:
                        System.out.println(tacks + curr.weight + ": sp");
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        System.out.println(tacks + curr.weight + ": nl");
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println(tacks + curr.weight + ": " + (char)curr.value);
                        break;
                }              
            }
            else
                System.out.println(tacks + curr.weight);
            tacks += "- ";
            getTree(curr.leftTree);
            getTree(curr.rightTree);
            tacks = tacks.substring(0, tacks.length()-2);
        }
        public int getSize() { return this.size; }
        public String encode(String input){
            String str = "";
            for (int x = 0; x < input.length(); x++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < valueTable.size(); i++) {
                    if (valueTable.get(i) == input.charAt(x))
                        str += pathTable.get(i);
                }
            }
            return str;
        }
        public String decode(String bits) {
            String decodedStr = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < bits.length(); i++) {
                if (!getChar(bits.substring(0, i+1)).equals("")) {
                    decodedStr += getChar(bits.substring(0, i+1));
                    bits = bits.substring(i+1);
                    i = 0;
                }
            }
            return decodedStr;
        }
        private String getChar(String bits) {
            String character = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < pathTable.size(); i++) {
                    if (pathTable.get(i).equals(bits))
                        character = valueTable.get(i).toString();
                }
            return character;
        }
    }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // for example assume that we have these letters with these different frequencies like below:
            int freq[] = {10, 15, 12, 3, 4, 13, 1};
            char code[] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 's', 't', ' ', '\n'};
            HuffTree hTree = new HuffTree(freq, code);
            System.out.println("Display Tree:");
            HuffNode curr = hTree.root;
            hTree.getTree(curr);
            System.out.println("");
            // and we want to build the huffman tree of the word sea :
            System.out.println("Encode 'sea': " + hTree.encode("sea") +"\n");
            System.out.println("Decode '" + hTree.encode("sea") + "': " +                                           hTree.decode(hTree.encode("tea")));
        }
}
```

Comment: How are you trying to open it? Was it exported as a runnable JAR?

Comment: by java(TM) platform SE binary

Comment: Are you sure it isn't opening and not closing right away? Your program doesn't have any interface and it doesn't ask for user input. Therefore it would run through the whole thing in a command prompt window and then close. Try running "java -jar JAR_FILE.jar" in a command prompt window from within the JAR's location.

Comment: Waaay too much code. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to help you ask a **minimum**, complete, and verifiable example.

Answer (score 1):

If it's simply not compiling into a jar file, try the following command in command prompt or terminal.

```
jar cf jar-file input-file(s)
```

From Oracle: [Creating jar File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)

To open command prompt, use WIN+R to open the run box, type cmd, and press enter.

navigate to the directory of your java file:

```
cd C:\Path\to\my\java\file\HuffNode.java
```

run the command:

```
jar cf HuffNode.jar HuffNode.java
```

If you have multiple .java files:

```
jar cf HuffNode.jar File1.java File2.java File3.java
```

Comment: I don't know how to use cmd , would you please explain it more

Comment: Also, like CConard62 said, try running the compiled jar from the command prompt instead of double clicking, that way you're making sure it isn't opening and closing real fast